# How can jQuery seemingly be both an object and a method invoked by an object?

Tags: javascript, jquery

There's a workaround function for an API object called [`unsafeWindow`](http://wiki.greasespot.net/UnsafeWindow) for browsers that don't support it ([via this person's github](http://mths.be/unsafewindow))

```
var unsafeWindow = (function() {
    var e1 = document.createElement('p')
    e1.setAttribute('onclick', 'return window;');
    return e1.onclick();
})();

// If the current document uses a JavaScript library, you can use it in
// your user script like this:
console.log(unsafeWindow.jQuery);
```

If `unsafeWindow` is an object (or in this case a function designed to mimic the object), how can it be used like `$ = unsafeWindow.jQuery`? I know this is how you map the function to the `$` instead of the `$` being a simple jQuery alias, but I'm just confused as to why, since I thought `jQuery` itself was an object, and is being invoked here like one would a method.

*Edit: Thank you for your answers, I wish I could "check mark" all of you, thanks for the help!*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `$ = unsafeWindow.jQuery` you are assigning the jQuery object to $ like you rightly pointed out. You are not invoking any function. Invoking a function in javascript involves adding a parenthesis `()` at the end.

Comment: as mentioned in another comment, I guess I saw the `.` and thought straight to "invoking" like one would in other languages. But to your comment on rightly assigning to `$` - it's not just the jQuery object, is it? What is happening here, where it looks like one object (the function unsafeWindow) is getting a property called jQuery, so what exactly is being assigned?

Comment: I think in the gist he has just mentioned a way to access the pages jQuery object. I suppose you can assign it to `$` like you mentioned or you can use it as it is `unsafeWindow.jQuery.("#myDiv").hide();`

Comment: right but I was wondering what property of `jQuery` is being accessed by the function object `unsafeWindow` (like `object.something` gets the property called `something`), now that I understand that functions are objects too... if that doesn't make sense then ok, but thanks for all your info/help so far!

Comment: The property it is accessing is the whole jQuery object with all its bells and whistles.

Answer (score 5):

In javascript, functions are objects!

Answer (score 2):

Don't let the `.` blindfold you. `object.something` is getting the property `something` which could be anything (function, variable, object, value..), while `object.something()` is applying the method `something`

Comment: you're right I was looking at the `.` and that's what mainly threw me towards the notion of invoking a method

Answer (score 1):

Jquery is a constructor function with methods attached. When used as `$.each()`, you are just calling the method `each()` that is attached to the function (object). When you use `$()`, it calls an internal `new jQuery()` and returns it, giving you access to it's prototype methods.